# PySpark - Drop Rows Conditional on Similar Row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, duplicates

I need to drop all the rows with dates that have a value of 0, where the same dates have a 1.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("A1", "2016-10-01", 1), ("A1", "2016-10-01", 0), ("A1", "2016-10-05", 1), ("A3", "2016-10-06", 1), ("A3", "2016-10-07", 0)], ["id", "date", "value"])

+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|value|
+---+----------+-----+
| A1|2016-10-01|    1|
| A1|2016-10-01|    0|
| A1|2016-10-05|    1|
| A3|2016-10-06|    1|
| A3|2016-10-07|    0|
+---+----------+-----+
```

**Desired Dataframe:** Notice how the date for `ID: A1` on `2016-10-01` had two values, 1 and 0. Now it only has a value of 1.

If a value of 1 exists for the same date with the value of 0, per group, the value of 0 needs to be dropped.

```
+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|value|
+---+----------+-----+
| A1|2016-10-01|    1|
| A1|2016-10-05|    1|
| A3|2016-10-06|    1|
| A3|2016-10-07|    0|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Comment: If you only have 1 row per value (1 or 0), use suresiva answer. otherwise, use mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just need some [`Window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) magic ✨

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df.withColumn("max_value", F.max("value").over(Window.partitionBy("id", "date"))).where(
    "value = max_value"
).drop("max_value").show()

+---+----------+-----+
| id|      date|value|
+---+----------+-----+
| A1|2016-10-05|    1|
| A1|2016-10-01|    1|
| A3|2016-10-07|    0|
| A3|2016-10-06|    1|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 4):

```
df.groupBy('id', 'date').agg(max('value').alias('value')).show()

+---+----------+----------+
| id|      date|   value  |
+---+----------+----------+
| A3|2016-10-06|         1|
| A3|2016-10-07|         0|
| A1|2016-10-05|         1|
| A1|2016-10-01|         1|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: This solution is the simplest.